# How do I retrieve multiple Count fields into a single User Report?

Tags: ravendb

Say I have a `User` class like this:

```
public class User
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Each User can be either a Mentor, a Mentee or both. This is represented by a `Relationship` class:

```
public class Relationship
{
   public string MentorId {get; set;} // This is a User.Id
   public string MenteeId {get; set;} // This is another User.Id
}
```

Now I would like to generate a report that lists all of my Users and contains a field called `Mentor Count` and another field called `Mentee Count`. To achieve this I have created a `UserReportDTO` class to hold my report data.

```
public class UserReportDTO
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string MentorCount {get; set;}
   public string MenteeCount {get; set;}
}
```

I then query my RavenDB to get a list of all the `Users` and transform this into a list of `UserReportDTO` instances.

**UserService**

```
public List<UserReportDTO> GetReportChunk(
    IDocumentSession db,
    int skip = 0,
    int take = 1024)
{
    return db.Query<User>()
            .OrderBy(u => u.Id)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Take(take)
            .ToList()
            .Select(user =>
                new UserReportDTO
                {
                    Name = user.Name,
                    MentorCount = // What goes here?
                    MenteeCount = // What goes here?
                })
            .ToList();
}
```

As you can see, I am struggling to work out the best way to retrieve the `MentorCount` and `MenteeCount` values. I have written some Map/Reduce Indexes that I think should be doing the job but I am unsure how to use them to achieve the result I want.

**Question**

What is the best way to include multiple aggregate fields into a single query?

---

**EDIT 1**

@Matt Johnson: I have implemented your index (see end) and now have a working Report Query which, in case anybody is interested, looks like this:

**Working User Report Query**

```
public List<UserDTO> GetReportChunk(IDocumentSession db, Claim claim, int skip = 0, int take = 1024)
{
    var results = new List<UserDTO>();
    db.Query<RavenIndexes.Users_WithRelationships.Result, RavenIndexes.Users_WithRelationships>()
        .Include(o => o.UserId)
        .Where(x => x.Claims.Any(c => c == claim.ToString()))
        .OrderBy(x => x.UserId)
        .Skip(skip)
        .Take(take)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(p =>
            {
                var user = db.Load<User>(p.UserId);
                results.Add(new UserDTO
                {
                        UserName = user.UserName,
                        Email = user.Email,
                        // Lots of other User properties
                        MentorCount = p.MentorCount.ToString(),
                        MenteeCount = p.MenteeCount.ToString()
                });
            });

    return results;
}
```

**MultiMap Index**

```
public class Users_WithRelationships :
        AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<Users_WithRelationships.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string[] Claims { get; set; }
        public int MentorCount { get; set; }
        public int MenteeCount { get; set; }
    }

    public Users_WithRelationships()
    {
        AddMap<User>(users => users.Select(user => new
        {
                UserId = user.Id,
                user.Claims,
                MentorCount = 0,
                MenteeCount = 0
        }));

        AddMap<Relationship>(relationships => relationships.Select(relationship => new
        {
                UserId = relationship.MentorId,
                Claims = (string[]) null,
                MentorCount = 0,
                MenteeCount = 1
        }));

        AddMap<Relationship>(relationships => relationships.Select(relationship => new
        {
                UserId = relationship.MenteeId,
                Claims = (string[]) null,
                MentorCount = 1,
                MenteeCount = 0
        }));

        Reduce = results => results.GroupBy(result => result.UserId).Select(g => new
        {
                UserId = g.Key,
                Claims = g.Select(x => x.Claims).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                MentorCount = g.Sum(x => x.MentorCount),
                MenteeCount = g.Sum(x => x.MenteeCount)
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better served with a model that already has your relationship data kept with the user.  This might look something like:

```cs
public class User
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string[] MentorUserIds { get; set; }
  public string[] MenteeUserIds { get; set; }
}
```

*However*, if you want to stick with the model you described, the solution is to get rid of the multiple separate indexes and create a single multi-map index that has the data you need.

```cs
public class Users_WithRelationships
           : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<Users_WithRelationships.Result>
{
  public class Result
  {
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MentorCount { get; set; }
    public int MenteeCount { get; set; }
  }

  public Users_WithRelationships()
  {
    AddMap<User>(users => from user in users
                          select new
                          {
                            UserId = user.Id,
                            Name = user.Name,
                            MentorCount = 0,
                            MenteeCount = 0
                          });

    AddMap<Relationship>(relationships => from relationship in relationships
                                          select new
                                          {
                                            UserId = relationship.MentorId,
                                            Name = (string)null,
                                            MentorCount = 1,
                                            MenteeCount = 0
                                          });

    AddMap<Relationship>(relationships => from relationship in relationships
                                          select new
                                          {
                                            UserId = relationship.MenteeId,
                                            Name = (string)null,
                                            MentorCount = 0,
                                            MenteeCount = 1
                                          });

    Reduce = results => 
                from result in results
                group result by result.UserId
                into g
                select new
                {
                  UserId = g.Key,
                  Name = g.Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                  MentorCount = g.Sum(x => x.MentorCount),
                  MenteeCount = g.Sum(x => x.MenteeCount)
                };
  }
}
```

Then you can update your `GetReportChunk` method to query against the one index if you still want to project a custom DTO.

```cs
return db.Query<Users_WithRelationships.Result, Users_WithRelationships>()
                 .OrderBy(x => x.UserId)
                 .Skip(skip)
                 .Take(take)
                 .Select(x =>
                         new UserReportDTO
                         {
                             Name = x.Name,
                             MentorCount = x.MentorCount,
                             MenteeCount = x.MenteeCount,
                         })
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: You'll beat me to the next one. :)

Comment: @Matt Johnson - Thanks. Please see Edit 1 in the question.

Comment: You're expecting too much to be done at time of reporting.  If .GetRegistrationWorkflow()  requires other fields from user, then you should run through this logic earlier in your workflow and persist the results so it can be easier queried upon.  If it's solely based on the input claim, then you don't need a full user materialized, do you.

Comment: OK, its all sorted now. Your `AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask` was the key. For the sake of completeness I put up the working query and projection into Edit 1 above.